# is there any difference in requiring a previous directory file with a slash at the begining?

Tags: php, include, include-path, slash

Say I am in `foo/bar/index.php` and want `foo/index.php`.

I require it by saying `require_once '../index.php';`
I saw somewhere that it is not good practice to do it like this, better to do prepend a slash making it `require_once '/../index.php';`

Can you explain me the difference and why one is better then the other?

Comment: did you mean **foo/index.php** ?

Comment: A leading slash makes the path absolute. For various reasons, the parent directory of root is root itself. So `/../index.php` is equivalent to `/index.php`.

Comment: @tripleee how can this be? `/index.php` is in a different location to `/../index.php`

Comment: `/index.php` is in the root directory. `/../index.php` is in the parent directory of the root directory. Like I mentioned, the parent of the root directory is the root directory. QED.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using `/foo/index.php` `../` will only take you one leve back. So, if your directory structure changes, you'll have to change all your links.

Build you links from the root forward, not the other way around if you can help it.

Comment: I know that, but I still want to know the difference!